# Variable not stored while executing bash commands via gnome-terminal

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, environment-variables

I have a plugin that generates and copies to the clipboard a ready-to-paste command which then creates a file that I want to move and rename via user input.

If I use this to get the latest modified file in the directory, then the file is correctly copied and renamed as specified in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=PROFILENAME --working-directory="/PATH/WAY" -x bash -c "$(xclip -se c -o); find /PATH/WAY -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort -r | head -n1 | grep -o "/home.*" | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' /PATH/TO/Desktop/test.txt; read -p 'Press Enter to close.'"
```

However, if I try to add the user input like this, then the variable does not seem to be set:

```
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=PROFILENAME --working-directory="/PATH/WAY" -x bash -c "$(xclip -se c -o); echo File name?; read newfile; echo File will be named $newfile.txt; find /PATH/WAY -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort -r | head -n1 | grep -o "/PATH.*" | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' /PATH/TO/Desktop/$newfile.flv; read -p 'Press Enter to close.'"
```

Because output says `File will be named .txt` while I'm expecting `File will be named USERINPUT.txt`, and the file is not copied.

Interestingly, if I use these commands in a bash script like this, then everything works ok:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo File name?
read newfile
echo File will be named $newfile.txt
find /PATH/WAY -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort -r | head -n1 | grep -o "/PATH.*" | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' /PATH/TO/Desktop/$newfile.txt
read -p 'Press Enter to close.'
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Ideally, this should be a script. It's a bit long for putting in one-line format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single big parameter after `bash -c` is within double quotes. That means, substitution of certain things (including `$newfile`) is performed here by the outmost shell, i.e. the shell that is about to launch gnome-terminal, before launching it. In that context this variable is undefined.

I recommend that you go for a separate script, as you've shown at the bottom of your post. The one-liners are terribly unreadable anyways.

Other possibilities include swapping `'` and `"` quotes in the command line so that `'` is the outer one (that is, `$newline` remains `$newline` and isn't substituted by the outmost shell, it's interpreted later by the one started by gnome-terminal); or escaping the `$` sign in `$newfile` as `\$newfile`.

And while we're at it:

`$(xsel ...)` executes the clipboard's contents as a command (or series of commands) without any validation whatsoever. E.g. if your clipboard contains the string `rm -rf ~`, your home directory is whoops gone. I'm not sure what your intent is, but for your safety, you should ditch this approach and find another solution!

`echo File name?` performs shell pattern matching on files whose names consist of five characters: `name` and then one arbitrary character. Use a pair of single or double quotes.

You refer to the variable name `$newfile` without quote marks. This will result in faulty behavior if it contains whitespaces. Refer to it as `"$newfile"` instead.

Comment: Thanks @egmont and @wjandrea, I'm going for a separate script (although I tested the swapping of `'` and `"` which also worked).
I modified the `echo` command for this post, the actual one is not in English, but I'll use quotes anyway, probably a good habit to take up!